# How do I keep this query out of mysql_slowlog?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT count, item, itemid
FROM items
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Takes .0011

Explain:

```
id  select_type table      type    possible_keys    key     key_len ref        rows Extra  
1    SIMPLE      items      index   NULL             count   4       NULL       20
```

I have indexes on itemid(primary key) and count (INDEX)

Does anyone have suggestions for how this could be better accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your [long_query_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) variable/setting is extremely short. The default is 10 seconds, but if your query is taking 0.0011 seconds, it obviously shouldn't be logged with the default setting. Try increasing it to something reasonable for your setup (1 second+ probably) and see if this still happens.

Comment: That's what I've done. However I also have it logging queries without indexes. Could that be causing it?